# Loop through rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Right now i have code like this :

```
Sub Loop2()


Dim str As String
str = "BLAH"
Dim X As Integer
    For X = 1 To 20
        Range("A" & X).Value = str
    Next X

End Sub
```

And this fills up the first column with "BLAH", but I want
to fill the first row instead, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use RANGE in the form of RANGE("A1"), the RANGE is more often use to define a start and end point ie. `RANGE("A1:A20")` or `RANGE("A1","A20")`.  If you are assigning a single value to a cell you may want to look at a CELLS.  CELLS will define it reference location using Row number and Column number ie `CELLS(15,4)` or `CELLS(15,"D")` would reference D15.  You can combine CELLS with to define the start and end point of your range numerically using:

```
RANGE(CELLS(1,1),CELLS(1,20))
```

which would be the equivalent of A1:A20

In your code replace `Range("A" & X).Value = str` with `CELLS(1,X).Value = str`

Comment: I think you meant CELLS(1, X), but it works now. Bonus question -- is this the best way to populate rows with particular objects?

Comment: @MichaelMao thank you and edit has been made

Comment: @MichaelMao I am not a VBA expert so not sure if its the best way or not.  One thing you could try with range and I am not sure if it will work is `RANGE(CELLS(1,1),CELLS(1,20)) = str`.  I am not sure if that will save you looping through each cell or not.